# Obtener un archivo externo y descargarlo en la misma solicitud

Tags: nodejs, fetch, download

lo que quiero hacer es una petición a un archivo externo mediante **fetch** y no guardarlo en el disco, sino hacer que siga la solicitud y que descargue el archivo, como si fuera un intermediario, ya que el archivo externo tiene ciertas restricciones de acceso.

Este es mi código para obtener el archivo externo, es un ejemplo de la misma documentación de **fetch**:

```
const cookieJar = new CookieJar(new FileCookieStore('./cookies.json'))
const fetch = fetchCookie(nodeFetch, cookieJar);
const response = await fetch('https://domain.com/example/archivo-externo/');
if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`unexpected response ${response.statusText}`);
await streamPipeline(response.body, createWriteStream('./filename.pdf'));
```

Este código obtiene el archivo pero lo guarda en disco, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que no guarde el archivo sino que siga el proceso y descargue en el navegador, ya intenté poniendo los headers de la request sin éxito.

Gracias de antemano.